# Predefined table head, add rows from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have a predefined table head like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="livsmedelsmall">
        <h1>Sökning av livsmedel</h1>

        <form class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="livsmedelsSokOrd">Livsmedel</label>
                <input type="search" class="form-control" id="livsmedelsSokOrd" placeholder="t ex makaroner">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sok-button">Sök</button>
        </form>
        <table id="tabell" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Livsmedel</th>
                    <th>Energi (kcal/100g)</th>
                    <th>Kolhydrater</th>
                    <th>Protein</th>
                    <th>Fett</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

<br>
```

And I want to add content to it from an array using this code:

```
// Work with the response
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); // server response

    var livsmedelArray = response.livsmedel;

    var table = $("#tabell");

    console.log(livsmedelArray);


    // Itererar genom samtliga rader i resultatet

    $.each(livsmedelArray, function(i, livsmedelArray) {

        // Skapar en tabellrad för varje apotek och hämtar ut respektive 
        // attribut för det aktuella apoteket och lägger in cellerna i tabellraden

        $('<tr><td>' + livsmedelArray.namn + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.energi + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.kolhydrater + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.protein + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.fett + '</td>'

            +
            '</tr>').appendTo(table);

        $("#tabell").show;

    });

}
```

However it does not work and I have no idea of why it doesn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your ajax is successful & response is correct. If it is so then you may need to target `tbody` for appending the `tr`

You can try this snippet

```
var trElement = '';
$.each(livsmedelArray, function(i, livsmedelArray) {

  // Skapar en tabellrad för varje apotek och hämtar ut respektive 
  // attribut för det aktuella apoteket och lägger in cellerna i tabellraden

  trElement += $('<tr><td>' + livsmedelArray.namn + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + livsmedelArray.energi + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + livsmedelArray.kolhydrater + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + livsmedelArray.protein + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + livsmedelArray.fett + '</td>'+
    '</tr>').
});
$('#tabell tbody').append(trElement)
```

Here the `trElement` variable is outside the `each` function. You can declare it inside the `success` function or as a separate variable.

Also dom manipulation is costly so, you can create a the complete object of `tr(s)` & append it at once.

Hope this will be useful

Comment: I get correct values from the array. However nothing is showing up in the table. What do you think could be the issue? Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be appending to body..
try this

```
var table = $("#tabell tbody");
```

***************EDIT***************

I am not sure about the rest of your code so why don't you try this..

```
var block = "";

$.each(livsmedelArray, function(i, livsmedelArray) {

 block+='<tr><td>' + livsmedelArray.namn + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.energi + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.kolhydrater + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.protein + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.fett + '</td>'+
        '</tr>';

});

table.html(block);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
// Work with the response
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response); // server response

    var livsmedelArray = response.livsmedel;

    var table = $("#tabell");

    console.log(livsmedelArray);


    // Itererar genom samtliga rader i resultatet

    $.each(livsmedelArray, function(i, livsmedelArray) {

        // Skapar en tabellrad för varje apotek och hämtar ut respektive 
        // attribut för det aktuella apoteket och lägger in cellerna i tabellraden

        $('<tr><td>' + livsmedelArray.namn + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.energi + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.kolhydrater + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.protein + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + livsmedelArray.fett + '</td>'

            +
            '</tr>').appendTo("#tabell");

        $("#tabell").show;

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the script, we need to just replace only .appendTo(table); with .appendTo('table');

Either we can replace the above script with below mentioned script:

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var livsmedelArray = response.livsmedel;
    var table = $("#tabell");
    console.log(livsmedelArray);    
    $.each(livsmedelArray, function (i, livsmedelArray) {       
        $('<tr><td>' + livsmedelArray.namn + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + livsmedelArray.energi + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + livsmedelArray.kolhydrater + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + livsmedelArray.protein + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + livsmedelArray.fett + '</td>'
        + '</tr>').appendTo('table');
        $("#tabell").show;
    });
}
```